# Distinguishing between yeast and bacteria

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, microscopy, staining

Can hematoxylin stain be used to tell apart yeast and bacteria cells
Are there any other method to tell apart yeast and bacterial cells?

I know hematoxylin stains histone protein but I am not sure how does it affects the bacterial cell so not sure if it will be full proof method to tell them apart( and it’s given that the cell I have is yeast cell or a bacterial cell)

Other method to tell them apart  I thought of is through microscope I think there will a size difference in yeast cell and bacteria cell but are there any other morphological features which can be used to tell them apart

So my first thought was to use a stain which only stains nucleus through which I came came across H&E staining but was not sure what affect it has on bacteria and I also saw other alternatives for hematoxylin but not sure about their affect their affect on bacteria for that I am thinking of setting up control (as stated in comments) will this be sufficient there may be other variables need to be taken into account?

And for antibiotics I was thinking was using a mixture of them but then I came across an answer in research gate saying chloramphenicol is used

So my main question is are the above stated method sufficient to distinguish between bacteria and yeast or are there any other efficient ways to distinguish them?
And the hematoxylin one too

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information.

Comment: Now is it fine?

Comment: Better, but it still needs work. What actual *research* have you done - web searches, literature searches through Google Scholar or your university's library, looking through microbiology textbooks? Have you simply searched for *`how to tell the difference between bacteria and yeast in the lab`*? What did you find when you did that? What do you still have questions about? Keep in mind that there are (roughly) two major kinds of bacteria - Gram positive and negative - and they have different types of cell walls. Also, remember that different bacteria range in size from tiny to gigantic.

Comment: So I am thinking I might not need to know how hematoxylin affects bacteria as I will stain the given sample in hematoxylin. And take a yeast cell and a bacteria cell  and stain them and compare these cell with the sample(which might be bacterial or yeast). And on comparison I make sure which cell is given in sample. This way there’s no need to know hematoxylin affect on bacteria

Comment: And also using antibiotics I have heard that chloramphenicol usually kill multiple bacteria but there might be some chances of survival is using a mixture of antibiotics recommended or chloramphenicol will be sufficient on its own

Comment: You should indicate whether you mean *any possible* yeast and bacteria, or specific ones of interest. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You should also include details of the research that you have done with references - in the body of the question. Comments are not permanent and should not be used as a substitute for editing the question with the relevant details.

Comment: I have made changes now is it fine